# How to check if the specified number of entries from one table matches the number of actual entries in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, one for the main and one for the contents

'Main' table:

```
pkey - pkey2  - contents

ABC1 - 11324  - 3
KJPO - 14124  - 4
PJKJ - 767172 - 5
```

'Contents' table

```
pkey - pkey2  - details

ABC1 - 11324  - some random info here
ABC1 - 11324  - some random info here
ABC1 - 11324  - some random info here
KJPO - 14124  - some random info here
KJPO - 14124  - some random info here
KJPO - 14124  - some random info here
```

The 'Main' table specifies the maximum number of contents that should be connected to the 'Main' table.

What I would need to have in my query is to get the lines from 'Main' table where the corresponding 'Contents' is not yet complete

i.e. the number of lines that matches the entries in main table has not reached (not equal) the number of contents specified in the 'Main' table.

It should return (based on the above example) like this:

'Main' table:

```
pkey - pkey2  - contents - missing

KJPO - 14124  - 4        - 1
PJKJ - 767172 - 5        - 5
```

I've tried making an inner join but cannot find it to work..
I'm thinking of just doing it on the client side e.g. vb.NET but I know it is not a recommended approach.  I hope someone can help me or at least lead me to another solution/work around, thanks in advance

EDIT:

I have added here a code from dav1dsmith:

```
select m.pkey, m.pkey2, m.contents, m.contents-isnull(c.actual,0) as missing
from dbo.Main m
left join (
    select pkey, pkey2, count(*) as actual
    from dbo.Contents
    group by pkey, pkey2
) c on c.pkey=m.pkey and c.pkey2=m.pkey2
where c.actual<>m.contents
```

the code works, but the result did not include entries from the 'main' table where there is no corresponding entry in the 'contents' table.. it shows lines that are incomplete but for only those that have at least one entry in the contents table.. as i said, the code is working, but im still trying to edit it to give what I needed

Comment: So what have you tried so far?  What problems are you observing with your attempt?

Comment: I've tried making an inner join but cannot find it to work.. I'm thinking of just doing it on the client side e.g. vb.NET but I know it is not a recommended approach. I hope someone can help me or at least lead me to another solution/work around, thanks in advance

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila - `I've tried making an inner join but cannot find it to work` - what was the problem ? Did you get an error ? You've asked a lot of questions here, so you know how this place works. You need to provide information to get help.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I find it useless to post my code here as i know it is preferred to get straight to the point.. I have codes that joins tables but i cannot make one that at least worked.. im thankful that you have also provided one that works but i find it hard to edit myself, but also i believe that "left join" might be the one that conflicts to the result that i've added in my edit above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select m.pkey, m.pkey2, m.contents, m.contents-isnull(c.actual,0) as missing
from dbo.Main m
left join (
    select pkey, pkey2, count(*) as actual
    from dbo.Contents
    group by pkey, pkey2
) c on c.pkey=m.pkey and c.pkey2=m.pkey2
where isnull(c.actual,0)<>m.contents
```

The derived table `c` resolves a `count(*)` of the rows in `dbo.contents` for each combination of `pkey` and `pkey2`.  Any combinations that don't exist will, obviously, not return a row in `c`.  The `dbo.main` table is `left join`ed onto these results - so that every row in `main` is returned in the result set regardless of whether any rows exist in the summarized `contents` table - using the same key columns.  The `where` clause filters out any rows that have the same number of rows in `contents` as predicted in the `main` table (I forgot the `isnull()` here initially - which was dropping rows from `main` where no corresponding `c` rows exist).  The initial column list then carries out the mathematics to calculate the `missing` column values.

Comment: let me try this first, will get back to you later

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for other readers.

Comment: hi, the code does not seem to return the lines from main table where there is no actual entry in the contents table.. ex. main table shows there 'should be' 3 contents, but there is not actual contents in the 'contents' table.. im not really adept in the joining statements, but i hope u can lead me to the right path

Comment: ok, i got it to work.. i just revised my 'where' clause, thanks dav1dsm1th!

Comment: I missed an `insull()` on the `where`.  Couldn't remember if a comparison with `null` removed the row from the result set (which it obviously dies) and was working without SQL...  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Please tell me if this queries works -

```
select s1.pkey, s1.pkey2, s1.contents, (s1.contents - s2.cnt1) as missing
from
(
select pkey, pkey2, contents 
from Main
) as s1
left join
(
select pkey, count(pkey2) as cnt1
from Contents
group by pkey
)as s2
on s1.pkey = s2.pkey
where (s1.contents - s2.cnt1) > 0
```

Comment: this also works, but please see my reply to dav1dsm1th's post, as the result is the same, thanks in advance =)

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila - tell me what is the problem in my code. If it helps, then please upvote it. If I not success, then my government will exceute me.

Comment: please see my reply to dav1dsm1th

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila - What is same about my code, other than the output ? I spent some time on this, so I'd appreciate an upvote if it worked for you.

Comment: it does not give what I asked.. but if you insist, for the effort rather, youll have ur upvote.. thanks

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila - In that case, please don't upvote. I tried the other query and got the same results. So, I did not see why there was a problem. Cheers.

Comment: yeah you got the same results, but not really.. i got the first one to work with simply editing the 'where' clause.. but i've tried yours, and found that i have to edit the 'on' clause and also the 'where' clause.. if an upvote is for everybody else that has an answer same with the first answer, then everybody could have just done that and get an upvote. yep you sorted out a part of the problem, but it was alredy answerd that's why i gave an upvote to him. and initially, i did not chose his as an answer.. i gave you an upvote bcoz the circumstnces, i believe, show that u hav an original answer

Answer (score 0):

As explained by dav1dsm1th the removed row derive from the `NULL` value in the `WHERE` condition (a condition with `NULL` always returns `FALSE`).

Actually the subquery can be removed and the grouping raised to the main query

```
SELECT m.pkey, m.pkey2, m.contents
     , missing = m.contents - COUNT(c.Details)
FROM   main m
       LEFT JOIN Contents c ON m.pkey = c.pkey and m.pkey2 = c.pkey2
GROUP BY m.pkey, m.pkey2, m.contents
HAVING m.contents <> COUNT(c.Details)
```

doing this the `COUNT` will always return something, even when there is no match between the two tables.